# How to create complex IEnumerable.GroupBy where keySelector is conditional?

Tags: c#, linq

I been grouping data-items by 3 fields with simple keySelector (type, classid, value), but now I need to have conditional keySelector for value that depends on type. It should work that different values of same type, classid are are sometimes combined to 1 group depending on type if certain condition (depending on type and number of items to be grouped) is met.

I have class I use in DataGrid :

```
public class MaintenanceDataItem
{
    public MaintenanceDataItem(int classId, Type objectType, object value, IEnumerable<MmsData> rows)
    {
        ClassId = classId;
        TypeOfObject = objectType;
        Value = value;
        ObjectIds = new List<int>();
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            Count++;
            ObjectIds.Add(row.ObjectId);
            if (row is MmsObservation && (row as MmsObservation).Urgency > MaxUrgency)
                MaxUrgency = (row as MmsObservation).Urgency;
        }
    }

    public int ClassId { get; private set; }

    public Type TypeOfObject { get; private set; }

    public object Value { get; private set; }

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public int MaxUrgency { get; private set; }

    public List<int> ObjectIds { get; private set; }
}
```

I have data classes e.g. MmsObservation that inherit abstract class MmsData. DataGrid ItemsSource-binding calls method:

```
private IEnumerable<object> GetSelectedObjectsMmsData()
{
       IEnumerable<MmsData> getMmsData;

       if (ShowOnlyFaults)
       {
           getMmsData = MaintenanceStore.GetMmsData(_selectedObjects.GetSelectedObjectItems(x => true)).Where(data => IsFault(data));
       }
       else
       {
            getMmsData = MaintenanceStore.GetMmsData(_selectedObjects.GetSelectedObjectItems(x => true));
       }
       var groups = getMmsData.GroupBy(
                   data => new { Type = data.GetType(), Id = data.MmsClassId, Value = data.Value}, (key, rows) => new MaintenanceDataItem(key.Id, key.Type, key.Value, rows));

       foreach (var item in groups)
       {
           yield return item;
       }
}
```

The condition when grouping is not straightforward is:

if objectType != MmsObservation and count > 1, the different values are grouped as ""

Comment: Why should it be a part of the `GroupBy`? Can't you have two different `GroupBy` statements and an `if`?

Comment: I wanted to solve it with some wizardry. I actually have solved this by putting there "" in case of objectType != MmsObservation which I later change to actual value if count=1.